# why are large sqlite transactions slow?

Tags: transaction, sqlite

So in the process of writing a migration wrapped in a transaction for a local web app, I realized that the migration appears to perform inserts very fast when the transaction has a small number of inserts (on the order of 100 milliseconds per insert), but performs slower when the transaction gets larger (upwards of 4 seconds per insert). I am working with a fairly massive amount of data for a single transaction (~40GB, 20,000 rows), but I don't understand what is actually slowing down the inserts or selects. The migration is essentially adding two columns to a table. The general workflow looks like:

1. start transaction
2. create new table w/ two additional columns
3. select old data needed to set additional columns
4. insert into table_new select from table_old
5. drop table_old
6. rename table_new to table_old
7. commit transaction

There are no indexes on any of the tables, though there is a non null foreign key pointing at another table. The full transaction is below:

```js
import Sqlite3 from 'better-sqlite3'

const TIMESTAMP_SQLITE = `TIMESTAMP DATETIME DEFAULT(STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%fZ', 'NOW'))`
const db = new Sqlite3('sqlite.db')
db.pragma('journal_mode = WAL')

function migrate() {
  const { media_file_count } = db.prepare('SELECT count(0) as media_file_count FROM media_file').get()
  const { media_chunk_count } = db.prepare('SELECT count(0) as media_chunk_count FROM media_chunk').get()
  db.exec(`
    CREATE TABLE media_chunk_new (
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
      media_file_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      chunk BLOB NOT NULL,
      bytes_start INTEGER NOT NULL,
      bytes_end INTEGER NOT NULL,
      updated_at ${TIMESTAMP_SQLITE},
      created_at ${TIMESTAMP_SQLITE},
      FOREIGN KEY (media_file_id) REFERENCES media_file(id)
    );
  `)

  const select_media_files_stmt = db.prepare('SELECT id FROM media_file')
  const select_media_chunk_stmt = db.prepare('SELECT id, LENGTH(chunk) AS chunk_size FROM media_chunk WHERE media_file_id = ? ORDER BY id')
  const insert_media_chunk_stmt = db.prepare(`INSERT INTO media_chunk_new
  SELECT
    id,
    media_file_id,
    chunk,
    @bytes_start AS bytes_start,
    @bytes_end AS bytes_end,
    updated_at,
    created_at
  FROM media_chunk
  WHERE id = @media_chunk_id`)

  let files_completed = 0
  let chunks_completed = 0
  for (const media_file of select_media_files_stmt.all()) {
    let bytes_start = 0
    for (const media_chunk of select_media_chunk_stmt.all(media_file.id)) {
      const bytes_end: number = bytes_start + media_chunk.chunk_size
      const info = insert_media_chunk_stmt.run({ media_chunk_id: media_chunk.id, bytes_start, bytes_end })
      if (info.changes !== 1) throw new Error('no changes occurred.')
      bytes_start = bytes_end + 1
      chunks_completed++
    }
    files_completed++
    process.stdout.write(`\rmigrated ${files_completed}/${media_file_count} media files (${chunks_completed}/${media_chunk_count} media chunks)`)
  }
  db.exec(`
    DROP TABLE media_chunk;
    ALTER TABLE media_chunk_new RENAME TO media_chunk;
    CREATE INDEX media_chunk_range ON media_chunk (media_file_id, bytes_start);
  `)
  console.log() // just flush the last line of output
}

db.transaction(migrate)()
```

Some additional context is that table being migrated (`media_chunk`) is used to store chunks of files (the `chunk` column). A column has a max BLOB size of 2Mib (`1024 * 1024 * 2` bytes). Could someone explain to me what exactly is the bottleneck here? I see the `sqlite.db-wal` file growing to the full size of the migration (40GB), but again, that doesn't actually spell out a problem as far as I can tell. I dont think table scanning is necessary. If possible, could someone explain how to improve the speed of a data migration like this too?

Comment: 40 GB at 4s is about 10 GB per second. The average NVMe disk can churn out about 2 GB per second sustained write speed. You're getting 5x the average write speed of an NVMe (not even counting the transaction logging in the WAL). Why do you consider this slow?...I think your bottleneck is the physical limitation of modern hardware.

Comment: I dont understand. Why do I need to process through all the data in the WAL file just to make one insert? The inserts are consistently the same size

Comment: Aren't you both selecting and inserting all of the existing data into a new table (your step 4)? If so, you're essentially telling SQLite to read and write 40 GB of data every time you do that.

Comment: if you look at the code in the question you'll see step #4 is only inserting for 1 row at a time. What is confusing about this to me is that that insert (`const info = insert_media_chunk_stmt.run({ media_chunk_id: media_chunk.id, bytes_start, bytes_end })`) becomes slower and slower the closer the migration gets to completion

Comment: so after some benchmarking, I think its possible this had more to do with the lack of an index on `media_file_id` than it had to do with a large transaction. I _think_ that running `select_media_chunk_stmt.all(media_file.id)` just so happened to have better performance earlier in the transaction because `media_file_id`s happened to be in order. Does that possible make sense? Or would it still have to scan the whole table on each select?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with the language you're coding in (since it's not a database language) but I understand the gist of it. An index would help performance on the look up portion of your code, though 20,000 rows to scan on is not really a lot in itself, but to scan them 20,000 times (assuming you're calling this once per row that you're migrating from the old table to the new one) could explain a runtime on the order of a few seconds, sure.